# stuck in array and string compare with strcmp c

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, char, strcmp

stuck in array and string compare with strcmp c 
why ist it working?? 
compiler got stuck at `if(strcmp(c,ch[i]) == 0){`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char ch[]="asdfghjkl";
    char c;
    int n=sizeof(ch)/sizeof(char);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(strcmp(c,ch[i]) == 0){
            printf("%c is in %d\n",c,i+1);
            break;
        }else if(i==n-1){
            printf("%c not fond\n",c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` takes two *strings* as arguments. You are passing a `char` and a string. Doesn't your compiler complain about it? Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function is for comparing *strings*. You want to compare *characters*.

Comment: type of `c` is `char` (one character, not string). `strcmp` requires `char *`.

Comment: maybe you should compare them directly? `c == ch[i]`

Comment: please please [mcve] with description of what is the *expected* result. What's wrong with `strchr`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your compiler *should* complain that you're using `strcmp` incorrectly: You are passing two chars to two `const char*`s which is definitely a UB. It'd be good if your compiler stops you from doing so by throwing an error.

The prototype for `strcmp` is (in `string.h`)

```
int strcmp(const char * s1, const char * s2);
```

Since you have two chars and `char` is a basic type, you can compare them directly:

```
if ( c == ch[i] )
```

Comment: It is not "UB", it is a constraint violation of the allowed forms of simple assignment. When passing parameters to a function, "...the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the
corresponding parameters" (6.5.2.2/7). Going from `char` to `char*` is not a valid form. Meaning that the compiler must give a diagnostic or it is not conforming.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of strcmp:
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

strcmp expects strings, but you are trying to pass char.

Use

```
if (c == ch[i])
```

Comment: Whats wrong in this? Can someone explain